# Downgrading framework to 4.0: The type or namespace name 'X' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, .net-framework-version

I wanted to set a few back to 4.0 but some unit test projects needed 4.5 and was getting errors like:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Util' does not exist in the namespace 'Foo' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I heard some people say that every project in the solution has to be the same version of the framework, so I created a separate solution file at the same directory for just the 4.0 ones and it still isn't working.  Same error message Any ideas?

Comment: Did you select the Client Profile version? I've always had weird issues like this when I accidentally chose it.

Comment: Are you actually getting errors about `Foo.Util` (a custom namespace, presumably with code being used to learn concepts), or is this some library? What library?

Comment: So you proved that this error doesn't actually have anything to do with downgrading the .NET version.  Best to chase the "are you missing an assembly reference" angle.

Comment: @TyCobb, I didn't choose the client profile version first. It gets even worse if I do that. "Foo" is me obfuscating our actual namespace names due to nondisclosure issues.  Util and 2 other projects are nondependent api's. I was adding projects into the new solution one by one.  I added a 'Common' api that depends on util and that worked fine.  I then added our Engine api which depends on Common and the 3 other nondependent api's and the Engine project doesn't like any of the project references.  If I revert back to 4.5, everything works fine, which is what I had to do for now.

Comment: I will try to upload a zip of our solution that can reproduce the problem. I just have to strip out some proprietary stuff first.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @DanCsharpster Yea, I was more wondering if you chose it by mistake. I didn't mean to switch it to that. The other time I have had that issue was with using BCL and not having it referenced in all projects. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion that every project in a solution has to be on the same version of the framework is incorrect.  It is legal to have projects targeting multiple versions of the .Net Framework and mulitple profiles in the same solution.  It's even possible to have references between them so long as the referencee's framework version is compatible with the referencer's framework version (4.5 can reference 4.0 but not the other way around).

Unfortunately to answer the specific question you asked we will need a bit more information about the projects in question.  My guess though is that you somehow broke the project references when you downgraded to 4.0.  I would first ensure all references were in the state I expected

Comment: I'll try to upload a 'working' example project.  The systems being build are an mvc project and a wcf service, but I'm having issues with the first couple of class library projects playing nice together in 4.0.